# What does authSource means in mongo database url?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, robo3t

i am trying to connect to my mongo database with following connection string

```
var Mongo_url = 'mongodb://MyUSer:tech@localhost:27017/chatme?authSource=admin';
```

I am getting error as

```
 assertionError: null == { [MongoError: Authentication failed.]
 name: 'MongoError',
 message: 'Authentication failed.',
 ok: 0,
 code: 18,
```

Could anyone please clear this "authSource=admin" thing to me.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is the name of the database that has the collection with the user credentials.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connections-connection-options

This is where the usernames and passwords are set up.

Comment: i have my users in system.users collection. So according to you 'authSource=admin' should be replace with authSource=users. right??

Comment: No, it's the name of the database, not the collection. And it defaults to the database you are trying to connect to. Does it work without the parameter?

Comment: yes it works without parameter too. I got it now. Thanks

Comment: Is --authSource=appDB and --authenticationDatabase=appDB the same?

Answer (score 6):

I spent a few hours today trying to solve this problem and unfortunately, this SO post didn't appear in my searches. That was too bad because it's the post with the best answer to the problem.

I hope to help the next person by adding the error message I got.

I'm setting up the connection inside a Docker container that is spun up via a docker-compose yaml file.  The user name and password are passed into docker-compose from a .env file.

Connection URI that works

```
mongodb://aUser:aPassword@mevn-app-mongo:27017/myDb?authSource=admin
```

Error:

```
SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for aUser on myDb from client 172.25.0.3:37352 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user aUser@myDb
```

Comment: I got this error when I was using NON-URL-ENCODED Connection SRV String

Comment: In my case, I was trying to login to a specific database as "root", but authentication was failing. Adding "authSource=admin" to the end of the connection string fixed it, thanks!