# Express.js application deployed to azure won't connect to mongoDB in cloud

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure

I deployed an express REST API using visual studio azure extension. It only consists of endpoints that serves JSON data. I have a few endpoints that it only serves and error message, those are working just fine, so the express application is working correctly but when I reach to an endpoint that requires to read from MongoDB, in visual studio, inside the streaming logs it prompts this:

**Error:**

```js
(node:68) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-02-cia4k.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to cluster0-shard-00-02-cia4k.mongodb.net:27017 closed
```

So as you can see it says it having a problem connecting, and I don't know what `failed to connect to the server, "connection 4"` means in this case.

I'm trying to connect an express application to MongoDB in the cloud. I'm using MongoDB Compass to visualize the data, and it doesn't have a problem connecting. These are the things that I made sure were correct.

- Network Access in MongoDB: Azure IP is registered in MongoDB (I found it in the "Custom Domain" tab in azure).
- Node.js has the correct Mongo address: `mongodb+srv://<MyUsername>:<MyPassword>@cluster0-cia4k.mongodb.net/<DatabaseName>`.
- I add this as a parameter at the end to the mongo address **mongodb+srv://...**`?authSource=admin`.
- I'm not trying to access a local MongoDB in the VM in Azure.

I already look at this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173080/mongonetworkerror-failed-to-connect-to-server-localhost27017-on-first-connec)  but I couldn't find something that helped me. Most of the problems in that post were locally in their computers.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution, So I wasn't wrong about one of the steps that I made but it required an extra setup. Basically the problem was this:

> Network Access in MongoDB: Azure IP is registered in MongoDB (I found it in the "Custom Domain" tab in azure).

It turns out that Microsoft Azure has multiple outbound IP Addresses. You can find them under the (Setting > Properties) > Outbound IP addresses. Put them all in MongoDB Atlas and that fixed my issue.