# MongoNetworkError on first connect using Docker and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I'm still incredibly new to coding. I'm trying to launch an app using docker, everything goes well until I get this error:

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:433:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at createConnection (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:577:14)
    at connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1007:11)
    at makeConnection (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:31:7)
    at callback (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:247:5)
    at Socket.err (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:276:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

I have mongodb running as a server on Windows 10, and I also have it running in another window, so I'm not sure what could be causing it. I've tried all solutions on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173080/mongonetworkerror-failed-to-connect-to-server-localhost27017-on-first-connec), but to no avail. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to use `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost`

Comment: What command are you using to bring up the container ?

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is the container, not your machine. When working with containers, you need to think of container as a separate machine and use a full network adressess to communicate between your machine and container.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a similar concept like yours. Try to run both `node-app` and `Mongo` service under the same network.

In `Mongo` connection string, the Hostname should be the same as your service name mentioned in `docker-compose.yml` file.

[image]

[image]