# Error when trying to connect to local MongoDB Server with nodeJS mongodb module

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The error I am receiving:

{ [MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:37017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:37017]]
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

*I had set the port while setting up my local database as 37017.

A mongo client in a separate terminal window is able to connect to the local server and execute commands. The problem occurs when I try to connect to the same server using a NodeJs application. I am attempting to run this simple code:

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YHYW.png)

**What I have tried:**

1.Reinstalling mongodb and restarting server

2.Using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Edit: ps confirms a mongod daemon is running

I am fairly new to nodeJs and MongoDB so debugging this error this early on has become a major headache! I am on a Mac running OS Catalina if that is related. Thank you!

Comment: this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173080/mongonetworkerror-failed-to-connect-to-server-localhost27017-on-first-connec, be sure you have the mongodb service running

Comment: Can you use `ps` to confirm that a `mongod` daemon is running?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that in my question but ps confirms a mongod daemon is running. A mongo client is able to connect to it.