# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017. server does not start

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to build a *node.js* API using *Express.js* and *MongoDB* I have called the libraries and *MongoDB*, also I have set a port and *MongoDB* connection.

When I execute the command `npm start`. The server starts but it still gives an error.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/subscribers', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started'));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server \[localhost:27017\] on first connect \[MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173080/mongonetworkerror-failed-to-connect-to-server-localhost27017-on-first-connec)

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue is old, but i came across a similar issue and the above solutions did not work for me, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

What i did to make it work was just running mongo service using this command:

```
$ mongod
```

Then everything worked fine

Comment: I am using windows. but the solution dint work for me

Comment: I also shared a solution for windows, you can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you already installed "MongoDB", if you accidentally exit from the MongoDB server, then "restart your system".

And also another method is there:

press:

```
Windows + R
```

type:

```
services.msc
```

and click "ok", it opens "services" window, and then search for "MongoDB Server" in the list. After you find "MongoDB Server", right-click and choose "start" from the pop-up menu.

The MongoDb Server will start running.

Comment: In services, the MongoDB server is up and running. Still I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

go into this directory in your file explorer

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin
```

then hold `Shift` key and press `mouse` Right button

then open `powershell window`

and type `mongod`
this will start your `mongo` server then try Running your `code`.

[see the pic it will work]

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/35nEn.png`